# Trying to understand meaning of below statement

Tags: javascript

What is exactly happening in this statement:

```
if (isNav4)
{
    obj = document[layerName].document; // This one
    if (itemName != "")
    {
        obj = obj[itemName];
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like this code is ancient... Like at least 20 years old? *I was playing with HTML Layers in Dreamweaver and JS 1.1 when I was a 2 year old kid. Now I am 27!*

Comment: This expression is about accessing a nested object, first with bracket notation and then with dot notation. Quite simply.